# Why is TOTP two-factor digits behaviour different between Android and iOS implementations of Google Authenticator?

Tags: google-authenticator

I have the below QR code generated from my application so users can use their phones for a time-based OTP. For Google Authenticator in iOS, scanning the QR code correctly leads to an eight-character time-based OTP generating every 30 seconds. However, **on the exact same Google Authenticator in Android, it incorrectly generates a six-character string instead.**

I have provided the sample string and QR code below (it's from a test system) - does anyone know why the implementation of the functionality differs between the exact same app on Android and iOS, or alternatively where I can find developer documentation for either the `otpauth` protocol or Google Authenticator itself (both seem thin on the ground and I've had to take what I can from tutorials)?

Sample string: `otpauth://totp/test@email.com?secret=GQ2DOMBXGRCDCMRSIVBEEOJSGMZEEQ2F&issuer=TestApplication&algorithm=SHA256&digits=8&period=30`

Sample QR Code: [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the Play Store version of Google Authenticator is proprietary, there is also [an open-source version](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-android).

Browsing through its wiki for [Key Uri Format](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format#digits), there is a remark for `digits` parameter.

> #### Digits
>
> **OPTIONAL**: The `digits` parameter may have the values 6 or 8, and determines how long of a one-time passcode to display to the user. The default is 6.
>
> > Currently, on Android and Blackberry the digits parameter is ignored by the Google Authenticator implementation.

So, apparently, the `digits` parameter is ignored in the Android version (along with other optional parameters like `algorithm` and `period` that are ignored on all platforms).

As far as I have tried searching for the specific reason why it is not implemented, I could not find it.

Comment: Thanks for that - what an odd thing to be different between the two versions. I'll mark this as the accepted answer. Looks like we'll be recommending a different app to our users that works properly across both platforms...